# Rails 3/JavaScript: Print PDFs to default printer

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that generates PDFs and I want it to be able to print the PDF to the client default printer. How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Edit: Javascript link could also work.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed javascript in your pdf.
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acro6JSGuide.pdf

So when you generate the PDF, use `this.print()` when the document is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Rails only sends the PDF to the browser, and the browser/user handles printing. You really can't control what printer it gets sent to...

Comment: Can't I do that in JS? A "Print" link that opens the printing options of the PC?

Comment: Yeah, but that would just show the standard print dialog. You can't choose for the user which printer to print to.

Comment: But can I choose to send a PDF to the printer and then the user chooses which printer he wants?

Comment: A Javascript `print()` will try to print the current page. When you send a PDF for download, it never exists as a 'page' that Javascript can run on.